# How to get display device's audio device in Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, driver

i need help in associating display devices with their relative audio devices, and in the end i want to have path to audio device using WinApi and C++.

The problem is that there is no straight way to accomplish this.

What i have now:
From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/device-properties) i can enumerate audio endpoint devices and some of them are are graphic card's audio:

```
#define EXIT_ON_ERROR(hres)  \
              if (FAILED(hres)) { goto Exit; }
#define SAFE_RELEASE(punk)  \
              if ((punk) != NULL)  \
                { (punk)->Release(); (punk) = NULL; }

const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);

void PrintEndpointNames()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDeviceCollection* pCollection = NULL;
    IMMDevice* pEndpoint = NULL;
    IPropertyStore* pProps = NULL;
    LPWSTR pwszID = NULL;

    hr = CoInitialize((LPVOID)NULL);

    hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
        (void**)&pEnumerator);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        hr = pEnumerator->EnumAudioEndpoints(
            eRender, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE | DEVICE_STATE_DISABLED | DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED,
            &pCollection);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        UINT  count;
    hr = pCollection->GetCount(&count);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        if (count == 0)
        {
            printf("No endpoints found.\n");
        }

    // Each loop prints the name of an endpoint device.
    for (ULONG i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // Get pointer to endpoint number i.
        hr = pCollection->Item(i, &pEndpoint);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

            // Get the endpoint ID string.
            hr = pEndpoint->GetId(&pwszID);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

            hr = pEndpoint->OpenPropertyStore(
                STGM_READ, &pProps);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

            PROPVARIANT varName;
        // Initialize container for property value.
        PropVariantInit(&varName);


        // Get the endpoint's friendly-name property.
        hr = pProps->GetValue(
            PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, &varName);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

            // Print endpoint friendly name and endpoint ID.
            printf("Endpoint %d: \"%S\" (%S)\n",
                i, varName.pwszVal, pwszID);

        CoTaskMemFree(pwszID);
        pwszID = NULL;
        PropVariantClear(&varName);
        SAFE_RELEASE(pProps)
            SAFE_RELEASE(pEndpoint)
    }
    SAFE_RELEASE(pEnumerator)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pCollection)
        return;

    CoUninitialize();
Exit:
    printf("Error!\n");
    CoTaskMemFree(pwszID);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pEnumerator)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pCollection)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pEndpoint)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pProps)
}
```

But how to detect which one's are graphic card's audio devices i don't know.

i also found a [structure that specifies information about a display-related digital audio device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ksmedia/ns-ksmedia-_tagksjack_sink_information)

and i tried to get some information from it by running this code :

```
#define EXIT_ON_ERROR(hres)  \
              if (FAILED(hres)) { goto Exit; }
#define SAFE_RELEASE(punk)  \
              if ((punk) != NULL)  \
                { (punk)->Release(); (punk) = NULL; }

HRESULT GetJackInfo(IMMDevice* pDevice)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IDeviceTopology* pDeviceTopology = NULL;
    IConnector* pConnFrom = NULL;
    IConnector* pConnTo = NULL;
    IPart* pPart = NULL;
    IKsJackSinkInformation* pJackInf = NULL;
    KSJACK_SINK_INFORMATION pJackSinkInformation;

    if (NULL == pDevice )
    {
        return E_POINTER;
    }


    // Get the endpoint device's IDeviceTopology interface.
    hr = pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IDeviceTopology), CLSCTX_ALL,
        NULL, (void**)&pDeviceTopology);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)



        // The device topology for an endpoint device always
        // contains just one connector (connector number 0).
        hr = pDeviceTopology->GetConnector(0, &pConnFrom);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        // Step across the connection to the jack on the adapter.
        hr = pConnFrom->GetConnectedTo(&pConnTo);
    if (HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND) == hr)
    {
        // The adapter device is not currently active.
        hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        // Get the connector's IPart interface.
        hr = pConnTo->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IPart), (void**)&pPart);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)


    hr = pPart->Activate(CLSCTX_ALL,
        __uuidof(IKsJackSinkInformation), (void**)&pJackInf);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    hr = pJackInf->GetJackSinkInformation(&pJackSinkInformation);


Exit:
    SAFE_RELEASE(pDeviceTopology)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pConnFrom)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pConnTo)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pPart)
        return hr;
}
```

`IMMDevice* pDevice` i got from executing previus code, and only usefull thing this code does, is `pPart->Activate`, fails when device is not a graphic card's audio device and when not, `pJackInf->GetJackSinkInformation` sets strange ids in `KSJACK_SINK_INFORMATION` structure, like : `PortId = {LowPart=3206951034 HighPart=-1360285969 }` when [CCD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/ccd-apis) api returns me `adapterId = {LowPart=56473 HighPart=0 }` for all displays. And i can't find a way to detect display's audio device.

I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Does `EnumAudioEndpoints` enumerate audio endpoint devices in a certain order? For example, start with graphics card or display device? In addition to the audio devices of the graphics card and display device, does it enumerate other endpoint audio devices?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT in my case it seams to be random, begins with graphics audio, and ends with it, and other audio devices are in the middle, but every time the order is the same. For me it enumerates all endpoint audio devices that i have.

Comment: @PuFF1k Have you found a solution? Im looking for a solution or something better than what I currently have. I found a few imperfect methods that when combined yields a decent solution, it matches device driver properties like `Container Id`, `Parent`, `Install date` & a couple other things & uses a bit of logic to cover as many cases as I can think. But Im looking for a better solution. I could piece together a maybe passable solution with everything Im thinking, but it'd be pretty ugly, & Im not sure if it'd cover every possible scenario, & Im bad with c++ :'(